# Create only blackscreen with subtitles from avi / flv file

Tags: video, video-editor, video-conversion, subtitle

I've got an interview in avi or flv format and I created subtitles (srt-file) for that. Which tool(s) can I use, to create a video file of minimal size, which only shows a picture/blackscreen and my subtitles?
Thanks, 
Felix

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: [see here](http://kiechle.e8u.de/fromm/technik.html)

Comment: What I really don't get: I have 62500 pictures. But the resulting video is only about 30 minutes instead of 62500/25/60 = 41,6 minutes

Comment: Hmm, it works with the outer loop x = 8. Then I have 100000 files and FM recognizes 62500 of them. I don't know what happend to the others, maybe some of the pictures got corrupted..